# Angular: Formatting numbers percentage

Tags: angular, numbers

l have data json contents on numbers in percentage and those numbers are `0.0` . l want to show only last number only ! .

I did as this, but he shows full number `0.13` % not only `13`

```
    <div>Delayed :percentage.delayed| number}} %</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

```
<div>Delayed : {{delayed | percent}} </div>
```

More Examples

https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [percent pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/PercentPipe). You are able to transform a number to a percentage string such as :

```
<p>A: {{a | percent}}</p>
```

or

```
<p>B: {{b | percent:'4.3-5'}}</p>
```

depending, how you want to format your number. Please, see the link above to see the examples of using percent pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use percent pipe which is as follows:

```
<div>{{Delayed:percentage.delayed | percent}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the pipe as

```
Delayed: {{percentage.delayed| number : '1.2-2'}}
```